# C#: SharpDX - Draw Basic Stars

Tags: c#, rendering, directx-11

***The Issue***

I've been searching for an answer to this issue for a few days now. I need help finding a way to generate a basic star. I have the code to randomly generate the locations done; however, I am new to `DirectX` and came from the world of `XNA` and `Unity`. `DirectX` development seems overly-complicated at the best of times. I have found a few tutorials, but, I am finding them difficult to follow. I have been unable to render anything to the screen once I've cleared it. I'm using the basic setup as far as rendering goes, I haven't created any special classes or structs. I have been trying to follow the [Richard's Software tutorials](http://richardssoftware.net/Home/DirectX11Tutorials) that were converted to C# from C++ in the book `3D Game Programming With DirectX 11` by `Frank D. Luna`. The farthest I have been able to successfully complete was clearing to `Color.CornflowerBlue`.

***Question(s)***

1. Are there any **simplistic** methods to draw/render objects to the screen, I'm able to render text just fine, but images (sprites) and 3D meshes seem to be giving me issues. Is there a simplistic method to draw basic geometric shapes? For example: `Primitives.DrawSphere(float radius, Vector3 location, Color c);`
2. If there aren't any simplistic methods available to draw primitives, what is going to be the simplest approach to rendering stars? I can do spheres, sprites with alpha blending to simulate distance, billboards, etc. What will be the simplest method to implement?
3. How do I implement the simplest method revealed by question 2 above? Code samples, tutorials (**no videos**), articles, etc. are greatly appreciated as I am having a hard time tracking down good C# references, it would appear that most are utilizing `Unity` and `Unreal` these days, but I don't have those options.

***Notes***

I work in a government environment and am **unable to utilize third party tools** that haven't been approved. The approval process is a nightmare so third party tools are typically a no go. All supplied answers, documentation, samples, etc. should be strictly utilizing `SharpDX`.

***My Code***

My project is a `WindowsFormsApplicaiton` where the primary form has been derived from `RenderForm`. I have created a single class called `Engine` that handles the `DirectX` code.

Engine.cs:

```
internal class Engine : IDisposable {

    #region Fields

    private Device device;
    private SwapChain swapChain;
    private DeviceContext context;
    private Texture2D backBuffer;
    private RenderTargetView renderView;
    private SynchronizationContext syncContext;

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event EventHandler Draw;
    public event EventHandler Update;
    private void SendDraw(object data) { Draw(this, new EventArgs()); }
    private void SendUpdate(object data) { Update(this, new EventArgs()); }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor(s)

    public Engine(RenderForm form) {
        SwapChainDescription description = new SwapChainDescription() {
            ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(form.Width, form.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
            BufferCount = 1,
            OutputHandle = form.Handle,
            IsWindowed = !form.IsFullscreen
        };
        Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, description, out device, out swapChain);
        backBuffer = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
        renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
        context = device.ImmediateContext;
        context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(renderView);
        context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
        renderForm = form;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Initialize() {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
            syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        else
            syncContext = new SynchronizationContext();

        RenderLoop.Run(renderForm, delegate() {
            context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.CornflowerBlue);

            syncContext.Send(SendUpdate, null);
            syncContext.Send(SendDraw, null);

            swapChain.Present(0, 0);
        });
    }
    public void Dispose() { }

    #endregion

}
```

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1: RenderForm {
    private Engine gameEngine;
    int count = 0;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        gameEngine = new Engine(this);
        gameEngine.Update += GameEngine_Update;
        gameEngine.Draw += GameEngine_Draw;
        gameEgnine.Initialize();
    }

    private void GameEngine_Update(object sender, EventArgs e) => Debug.WriteLine("Updated.");
    private void GameEngine_Draw(object sender, EventArgs e) => Debug.WriteLine($"I've drawn {++count} times.");
}
```

***Final Remarks***

Any help is appreciated at this point because its going on day 4 and I am still struggling to understand most of the `DirectX 11` code. I am by no means new to `C#` or development; I am just used to `Windows Forms`, `ASP.NET`, `Unity`, `XNA`, `WPF`, etc. This is my first experience with `DirectX` and its definitely over the top. Even worse than when I tried `OpenGL` ten years ago with hardly any development experience at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things to start with.

First, DirectX is a very low level API. The only way to get a lower level API on Windows is to go talk to the graphics driver directly, which would be even more of a nightmare. As a result, things tend to be extremely generic, which allows for high flexibility at the cost of being fairly complicated. If you ever wondered what Unity or Unreal were doing under the hood, this is it.

Second, DirectX, and Direct3D in particular, is written in and for C++. C# resources are hard to come by because the API wasn't really intended for use from C# (not that that's a good thing). As a result, discarding the documentation and answers written for C++ is a really bad idea. All the caveats and restrictions on the C++ API also apply to you in the C# world, and you will need to know them.

Third, I will not be able to provide you an entirely C#/SharpDX answer, since I don't use DirectX from C#, but from C++. I'll do what I can to provide accurate mappings, but be aware you are using an API wrapper, which can and will hide some of the details from you. Best option to discover those details would be to have the source code of SharpDX up as you go through the C++ documentation.

Now on to the questions you have. Strap in, this will be long.

First up: there's no simple way to render a primitive object in Direct3D 11. Rendering a six faced cube has the same steps as rendering a 200 million vertex mesh of New York City.

In the rendering loop, we need to do several actions to render anything. In this list, you've already done step 1 and 7, and partially done step 2:

1. Clear the back buffer and depth/stencil buffers.
2. Set the input layout, shaders, pipeline state objects, render targets, and viewports used in the current rendering pass.
3. Set the vertex buffer, index buffer, constant buffers, shader resources and samplers used by the current mesh being drawn.
4. Issue the draw call for the given mesh.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all meshes that must be drawn in the current rendering pass.
6. Repeat steps 2 through 5 for all passes defined by the application.
7. Present the swap chain.

Fairly complex, just to render something as simple as a cube. This process needs several objects, of which we already have a few:

- A `Device` object instance, for creating new D3D objects
- A `DeviceContext` object instance, for issuing drawing operations and setting pipeline state
- A `DXGI.SwapChain` object instance, to manage the back buffer(s) and present the next buffer in the chain to the desktop
- A `Texture2D` object instance, to represent the back buffer owned by the swap chain
- A `RenderTargetView` object instance, to allow the graphics card to use a texture as the destination for a rendering operation
- A `DepthStencilView` object instance, if we're are using the depth buffer
- `VertexShader` and `PixelShader` object instances, representing the shaders used by the GPU during the vertex and pixel shader stages of the graphics pipeline
- An `InputLayout` object instance, representing the exact layout of one vertex in our vertex buffer
- A set of `Buffer` object instances, representing the vertex buffers and index buffers containing our geometry and the constant buffers containing parameters for our shaders
- A set of `Texture2D` object instances with associated `ShaderResourceView` object instances, representing any textures or surface maps to be applied to our geometry
- A set of `SamplerState` object instances, for sampling the above textures from our shaders
- A `RasterizerState` object instance, to describe the culling, depth biasing, multisampling, and antialiasing parameters the rasterizer should use
- A `DepthStencilState` object instance, to describe how the GPU should conduct the depth test, what causes a depth test fail, and what a fail should do
- A `BlendState` object instance, to describe how the GPU should blend multiple render targets together

Now, what does this look like as actual C# code?

Probably something like this (for rendering):

```
//Step 1 - Clear the targets
// Clear the back buffer to blue
context.ClearRenderTargetView(BackBufferView, Color.CornflowerBlue);
// Clear the depth buffer to the maximum value.
context.ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilBuffer, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);

//Step 2 - Set up the pipeline.
// Input Assembler (IA) stage
context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = VertexBufferLayout;
// Vertex Shader (VS) stage
context.VertexShader.Set(SimpleVertexShader);
// Rasterizer (RS) stage
context.Rasterizer.State = SimpleRasterState;
context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
// Pixel Shader (PS) stage
context.PixelShader.Set(SimplePixelShader);
// Output Merger (OM) stage
context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(DepthStencilBuffer, BackBufferView);
context.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(SimpleDepthStencilState);
context.OutputMerger.SetBlendState(SimpleBlendState);

//Step 3 - Set up the geometry
// Vertex buffers
context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer, sizeof(Vertex), 0));
// Index buffer
context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, Format.R16_UInt, 0);
// Constant buffers
context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, TransformationMatrixBuffer);
context.PixelShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, AmbientLightBuffer);
// Shader resources
context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, MeshTexture);
// Samplers
context.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, MeshTextureSampler);

//Step 4 - Draw the object
context.DrawIndexed(IndexBuffer.Count, 0, 0);

//Step 5 - Advance to the next object and repeat.
// No next object currently.

//Step 6 - Advance to the next pipeline configuration
// No next pipeline configuration currently.

//Step 7 - Present to the screen.
swapChain.Present(0, 0);
```

The vertex and pixel shaders in this example code expect:

- A model with position, normal, and texture coordinates per vertex
- The position of the camera in world space, the world-view-projection matrix, world inverse transpose matrix, and world matrix as a vertex shader constant buffer
- The ambient, diffuse, and specular colors of the light, as well as its position in the world, as a pixel shader constant buffer
- The 2D texture to apply to the surface of the model in the pixel shader, and
- The sampler to use when accessing the pixels of the above texture.

Now the rendering code itself is fairly simple - the setup is the harder part of it:

```
  //Create the vertex buffer
  VertexBuffer = new Buffer(device, RawVertexInfo, new BufferDescription {
    SizeInBytes = RawVertexInfo.Length * sizeof(Vertex),
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vertex)
  });
  //Create the index buffer
  IndexCount = (int)RawIndexInfo.Length;
  IndexBuffer = new Buffer(device, RawIndexInfo, new BufferDescription {
    SizeInBytes = IndexCount * sizeof(ushort),
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.IndexBuffer,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    StructureByteStride = sizeof(ushort)
  });
  //Create the Depth/Stencil view.
  Texture2D DepthStencilTexture = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription {
    Format = Format.D32_Float,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    Height = renderForm.Height,
    Width = renderForm.Width,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription {
      Count = 1,
      Quality = 0,
    },
    CpuAccessFlags = 0,
    OptionFlags = 0
  });
  DepthStencilBuffer = new DepthStencilView(device, DepthStencilTexture);
  SimpleDepthStencilState = new DepthStencilState(device, new DepthStencilStateDescription {
    IsDepthEnabled = true,
    DepthComparison = Comparison.Less,
  });
  //default blend state - can be omitted from the application if defaulted.
  SimpleBlendState = new BlendState(device, new BlendStateDescription {

  });
  //Default rasterizer state - can be omitted from the application if defaulted.
  SimpleRasterState = new RasterizerState(device, new RasterizerStateDescription {
    CullMode = CullMode.Back,
    IsFrontCounterClockwise = false,
  });
  // Input layout.
  VertexBufferLayout = new InputLayout(device, VertexShaderByteCode, new InputElement[] {
    new InputElement {
      SemanticName = "POSITION",
      Slot = 0,
      SemanticIndex = 0,
      Format = Format.R32G32B32_Float,
      Classification = InputClassification.PerVertexData,
      AlignedByteOffset = 0,
      InstanceDataStepRate = 0,
    },
    new InputElement {
      SemanticName = "NORMAL",
      Slot = 0,
      SemanticIndex = 0,
      Format = Format.R32G32B32_Float,
      Classification = InputClassification.PerVertexData,
      AlignedByteOffset = InputElement.AppendAligned,
      InstanceDataStepRate = 0,
    },
    new InputElement {
      SemanticName = "TEXCOORD0",
      Slot = 0,
      SemanticIndex = 0,
      Format = Format.R32G32_Float,
      Classification = InputClassification.PerVertexData,
      AlignedByteOffset = InputElement.AppendAligned,
      InstanceDataStepRate = 0,
    },
  });
  //Vertex/Pixel shaders
  SimpleVertexShader = new VertexShader(device, VertexShaderByteCode);
  SimplePixelShader = new PixelShader(device, PixelShaderByteCode);
  //Constant buffers
  TransformationMatrixBuffer = new Buffer(device, new BufferDescription {
    SizeInBytes = sizeof(TransformationMatrixParameters),
    BindFlags = BindFlags.ConstantBuffer,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
  });
  AmbientLightBuffer = new Buffer(device, new BufferDescription {
    SizeInBytes = sizeof(AmbientLightParameters),
    BindFlags = BindFlags.ConstantBuffer,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
  });
  // Mesh texture
  MeshTexture = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription {
    Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    Height = MeshImage.Height,
    Width = MeshImage.Width,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 0,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription {
      Count = 1, 
      Quality = 0,
    }
  });
  //Shader view for the texture
  MeshTextureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, MeshTexture);
  //Sampler for the texture
  MeshTextureSampler = new SamplerState(device, new SamplerStateDescription {
    AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
    AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
    AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Border,
    BorderColor = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawColor4(255, 0, 255, 255),
    Filter = Filter.MaximumMinMagMipLinear,
    ComparisonFunction = Comparison.Never,
    MaximumLod = float.MaxValue,
    MinimumLod = float.MinValue,
    MaximumAnisotropy = 1,
    MipLodBias = 0,
  });
```

As you can see, there's a lot of stuff to get through.

As this has already gotten a lot longer than most people have the patience for, I'd recommend getting and reading the book by Frank D. Luna, as he does a much better job of explaining the pipeline stages and the expectations Direct3D has of your application.

I'd also recommend reading through the C++ documentation for the Direct3D API, as, again, everything there will apply to SharpDX.

In addition, you'll want to look into HLSL, as you'll need to define and compile a shader to make any of the above code even work, *and* if you want any texturing, you'll need to figure out how to get the image data into Direct3D.

On the bright side, if you manage to implement all of this in a clean, extensible manner, you'll be able to render practically anything with little additional effort.

Comment: This was a very detailed answer and has helped me greatly. Thank you for taking the time and effort to write this. It is a great starting point, and gives me a lot to look into to minimalize the effort needed in the future. Thank you for the added point on HLSL as well, I already have experience writing shaders thanks to XNA, but I didn't know it was 100% required by DirectX so that was also a very great point to bring forward!

Comment: As of D3D 10, shaders are the only method for rendering anything. In previous versions, there was a fixed function pipeline, with a "flexible vertex format" that told D3D where that information was in the vertex structure, but as of D3D 9.0c, that pipeline was deprecated, and by D3D 10 and Vista it was removed completely. If any toolkit has a fixed function pipeline currently, it's built on top of a set of predefined shaders.